# Using variable value as variable name in bash

Tags: bash, variables, variable-names

I've seen this question asked before but I can't seem to get the grasp of it.

I have this variable that I get from user input
`read column_number`

and then I join it with the "col" prefix to form the name of my variable

```
selected_column="col"$column_number
```

But when I try to evaluate it to get the result, I keep getting the (standard_in) 1: syntax error

```
sum=$(round $sum+"echo ${!selected_column}", 2)
```

[full code:](http://pastebin.com/1VFtXUZu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
column_number=5
selected_column=col$column_number
col5=42
sum=17
echo $(($sum+${!selected_column}))
```

Output:

```
59
```

---

```
sum=$(round $(($sum+${!selected_column})) 2)
```

Comment: Please could you give an explanation of `${!selected_column}`  Is it the history expansion feature that we are using here?

Comment: @sjsam: From `man bash`: "*If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash  uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and
       that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is known  as  indirect
       expansion.*"

Comment: @gboffi : Wow !! Cheers pal !! Helped.

Comment: Thank you!! it actually worked, although i had to tweak it a bit because it was interfering with the round function, so the actual usage (when it comes to the full code) is this: 
`sum=$(round $sum+${!selected_column} 2)`